# Handling M2M relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, relationship, manytomanyfield

I have a User model that extends the built in Django User model:

```
class CustomUser(User):
    objects = UserManager()
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task)
```

I created a User in the shell using:

```
user=CustomUser.objects.create_user('fred', 'fred@gmail.com', 'fredpass')
```

I have another model for Tasks and as you can see CustomUser has a manytomanyfield relating it to Task.

How would I add and remove tasks that have already been created to be associated with the user I have created?

Answer (score 1):

```
P=Project.objects.get(pk=1)
task=p.task_set.get(task_name='Task1')
user1=CustomUser.objects.get(username='john')
user1.tasks.add(task)
```

This was my solution